# VSCode error squiggles no longer appearing for my ASP.Net Core projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I just recently noticed that my VS Code (running on MacOS) has stopped putting error squiggles in undeclared variables/methods.

I read somewhere that I needed to have an SLN file (I never had to before), and so I created it and referenced my CSPROJ files.

I also saw that my Omnisharp stopped working as it was getting timed out. I increased the timeout to 600 and got it running.

I still am not seeing the error squiggles, though.

How do I get this feature enabled again?

Comment: Did you uninstall/install any extensions since then?

Comment: A recent one was installing Azure Application Insights.

Comment: I reinstalled Mono and it worked.